# Prove that $x/((e+x)\ln(e+x)) \leq \ln(\ln(e+x)) \leq x/e$ for all $x > 0$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, inequality, logarithms, integral-inequality

I've been working on a problem but have been stuck for several hours finishing it.

The problem is to show that
$$
  \frac{x}{(e+x) \ln(e+x)} \leq \ln(\ln(e+x)) \leq \frac{x}{e}
$$
for all $x > 0$.

I proceeded by first integrating each component as the problem suggested, which changed it to proving that
$$
\int_0^x \frac{1}{(e+x) \ln(e+x)} \,\mathrm{d}t
\leq
\int_0^x \frac{1}{(e+t) \ln(e+t)} \,\mathrm{d}t
\leq
\int_0^x \frac{1}{e} \,\mathrm{d}t \,.
$$

From here I was able to show quite easily that when $x>0$, the second inequality holds. However, I'm unsure of how to now prove the first inequality: is there a result which could help with this or something that I'm missing?

Thanks very much for any help, and sorry for the poor formatting, it's my first time using stack exchange.

Mark

Comment: Please check my edit and continue with the rest. Look up Mathjax for other options.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I wasn't sure of the formatting.  I'll edit the rest now.

Comment: Are you sure the hint was to integrate?  If it not true that if $\inf f < \int g$ then $f<g$.  However, it is true that if $f(0)=g(0)$ and $f'(x)<g'(x)$ then $f(x)<g(x) $ for all $x\geq 0$.

Comment: The question asks to write $ln(ln(e+x))$ in terms of an integral, but I believe it can be done any way we can manage.

Comment: @MarkH9664 Can you clarify "proceeded by first integrating each component as the problem suggested"? IE It didn't seem to me that you integrated the exact component. $\quad$ Maybe look at my solution, which closely mirrors yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

Let $u = \ln(e + x)$ (observe that $u\geq 1$). Then one has that
\begin{align*}
\frac{x}{(e + x)\ln(e + x)} \leq \ln(\ln(e + x)) & \Longleftrightarrow \frac{e^{u} - e}{e^{u}u} \leq \ln(u)
\end{align*}

If we let $u = 1$, both the RHS and the LHS equals zero.

Now we can take the difference and differentiate it:
\begin{align*}
f(u) := \frac{1}{u} - \frac{e^{1 - u}}{u} - \ln(u) \Rightarrow f'(u) & = -\frac{1}{u^{2}} + \frac{e^{1-u}u + e^{1-u}}{u^{2}} - \frac{1}{u}\\\\
& = \frac{e^{1 - u}(u  + 1) - (u + 1)}{u^{2}}\\\\
& = \frac{(e^{1 - u} - 1)(u + 1)}{u^{2}}
\end{align*}

Consequently, the proposed relation holds iff $f'(u) < 0$ for $u\geq 1$. Indeed, this is the case (why?).

For the other inequality, consider the same substitution $u = \ln(e + x)$ (once again, $u\geq 1$).

Then we have the following equivalence:
\begin{align*}
\ln(\ln(e + x)) \leq \frac{x}{e} \Longleftrightarrow 
\ln(u) \leq \frac{e^{u} - e}{e}
\end{align*}

If we let $u = 1$, both the RHS and LHS equals zero.

Once again, we are going to take the difference and differentiate it:
\begin{align*}
g(u) := \ln(u) - e^{u - 1} + 1 \Rightarrow g'(u) & = \frac{1}{u} - e^{u-1}
\end{align*}

Analogously, the proposed relation holds iff $g'(u) < 0$ for every $u\geq 1$. Indeed, this is the case (why?).

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Thank you for such a thorough answer, I hadn't even considered using substitution.  I've ran it through and everything is clear.

Comment: @MarkH9664 you are welcome! I am glad I could help.

Answer (score 4):

Using just the integral definition of $\ln$, we have

$$\ln (\ln(e+x)) = \int_1^{\ln(e+x)} \frac{dt}{t} \geqslant \frac{\ln(e+x) -1}{\ln(e+x)} = \frac{\ln (e \cdot (1+x/e))-1}{\ln(e+x)} = \frac{\ln(1+x/e)}{\ln(e+x)} \\= \frac{1}{\ln(e+x)}\int_1^{1+ x/e} \frac{dt}{t}\geqslant \frac{1}{\ln(e+x)}\frac{x/e}{1+x/e}= \frac{x}{(e+x)\ln(e+x)}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $ f(x) = \ln ( \ln (e+x) ) $.

1. Show that $ f'(x) = \frac{1}{(e+x)( \log e+x)} $.
2. Show that $f(0) = 0 $.
3. Show that for $X> x$, $$ \frac{1}{ ( e+X) \log (e + X) } \leq f'(x) \leq \frac{1}{e}.$$
4. Consider $ \int_0^X f'(x) \, dx$ and derive the desired inequality
   $$ \frac{X}{ ( e+X) \log (e + X) } \leq \ln ( \ln (e+X)) \leq \frac{X}{e}.$$